# Have Nike's sales jumped 31% after signing Kaepernick?

Tags: marketing

Many news orgs are writing about Nike's online sales jump of 31%, [like this one from NBC](https://www.nbcnews.com/business/business-news/what-boycott-nike-sales-are-31-percent-kaepernick-campaign-n908251) or [this one from Market Watch](https://www.marketwatch.com/story/nikes-online-sales-jumped-31-after-company-unveiled-kaepernick-campaign-2018-09-07).

> Nike sales jumped by 31 percent after debuting quarterback-turned-activist Colin Kaepernick as a new company spokesman — and market observers say the president’s public displays of anger may have backfired by drawing more attention to Nike.

This sales jump is from sales data from Sunday, September 2, 2018 through Tuesday, September 4, and is comparing year over year sales.

That being said, Nike didn't announce the partnership until Labor Day (the 3rd) and didn't air the commercial until Thursday the 6th.

The clear intent of the article is that the partnership between Kaepernick and Nike and the message of the ad directly contributed to Nike's 31% year-over-year increase in sales.

However, the claim that the online sales jumped 31% due *solely* to the ad is, to me, suspect as the dates involved include non-campaign days and the Labor Day event included other promotions by both Nike and its distributors.

It is true to state that Nike's sales jumped by 31%, however, it seems false to attribute that jump solely to the partnership, if not least because of the inclusion of non-campaign days in the data.

So, what was the real sales jump due to the partnership and ad with Kaepernick?

Comment: This was designed to spread fast. People where already burning Nike products on the 3rd so it shouldn't be surprising that people where also buying at the same time. https://pjmedia.com/trending/conservatives-burn-shoes-after-nike-makes-colin-kaepernick-face-of-just-do-it-campaign/

Comment: @JoeW - it spread like wildfire, that's for sure. Still, I can't find tweets that predate the announcement on the 3rd. This calls into question the applicability of of the campaign to sales on the 2nd. The real picture may be from the 3rd on because of the fast spread, but I'd still like to see the numbers from the 3rd to date and from the 6th to date...if at all possible. As that's the real story behind the campaign.

Comment: I am guessing they did the 2nd to the 4th is because the marketing and sales data is focused around those dates since it is for the Labor day holiday in general. Also I am not sure why the commercial air date matters at all since even you admit people where reacting to the announcement on the 3rd. I would guess if they where to release a breakdown of sales on those three days you would see the increase on the 3rd and 4th after the announcement.

Comment: @JoeW Not everyone is on social media (though the target market for this campaign most assuredly are). Nike also ran Labor Day sales, as did most, if not all, of their distributors. So, the sales spike being 100% attributed to this campaign is suspect. What I'm asking for is sales data for the time period following the announcement and campaign. It may not be of interest to you, but it is to me. Hence, the question.

Comment: Hi, all questions on skeptics need to be about a notable claim. Can you please focus your question so it does not ask for speculation ("can a 31% jump be attributed to...")?

Comment: Where did you get your understanding about the dates of the sales jump. The source of that isn't clear.

Comment: The claim is that the jump was *after* the debut. Is that not enough? (Causation is a.much stronger claim than correlation. Causation due to adverts is much harder to prove.)

Comment: @Oddthinking except it wasn't. I'm a marketing professional and can tell you that if I include non campaign dates in my campaign report then I would lose all credibility. There was a bump. It wasn't 31%. What was it?

Comment: Ah, I think I see the problem. Skeptics.SE has this really weird scope of what's on topic. We don't take on any general knowledge question, but tackle claims that are widely believed. In this case, the claim is clearly that Nike's sales jumped 31% after (or even stronger, because of) Kaepernick's debut. So that's why I focused the question on that, rather than "What what the sales jump?"

Comment: @Oddthinking I attempted an edit to clarify things. If I made the question off topic (again) please let me know and I'll revert it. Thanks!

Comment: Since both articles compare the 31% post-Labor Day increase to last year's 17% increase, it might be more fair to say the articles are claiming the ad announcement contributed to the ~14% jump in sales, rather than the full 31% .

Comment: @Giter that *is* possible but I have my doubts. Let's say, for example, that Sunday's sales were 50% YoY, Labor Day was 25%, and the 4th was 18%. The combined average would be 31% YoY but the main jump was made *prior* to the campaign announcement, let alone the campaign ad. The most one could say, in my example, is that the ad had an avg. 21.5% effect. The dates matter, and the inclusion of the 2nd in the report leads me to suspect that it played a contributing role to the overall average and that this is disingenuous.

Comment: Neither of the articles make the claim that the increase is solely due to the partnership. They're saying that sales haven't dropped. "What boycott", and "fears of a hit are overblown"

Comment: I am fairly certain the 31% corresponds to online sales, which is how I saw it phrased in articles, and, also, since there would be no way to get feedback that quickly on traditional retail sales. Also, since this is when they roll out their promotional ad campaigns, they usually see a jump in sales, so the 31% increase would be comparing pre-promotions vs post, and not normal increases in sales with promotions in other years vs. Kaepernick promotion numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The 31% stat appears to come from [Edison Trends](https://web.archive.org/web/20180911072524/https://trends.edison.tech/research-nike-labor-day-2018.html), which has this chart (an interactive version can be found [here](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2018-09-11/nike-colin-kaepernick-ad-sales-chart/10221720)):

> [image]
>
> "1x" means "1x the number of Nike product orders sold on August 1, 2017." Data collected from receipts from over 200 online vendors, using "Nike" as a search term.

Checking the math, it was .83x on Sunday and 1.08x on Tuesday and .83 × .31 + .83  ≈ 1.08

As the chart says, it's an increase in *online* sales. Because last year's graph also shows an increase (17% between Sunday and Tuesday), it is doubtful that this increase is entirely due to the advertisement.

Comment: Good answer. It might be useful to mention that the articles referenced by the question say exactly this. They state the statistic is online sales, and reference the previous year's 17% increase over the same period. I.e. what they claim is accurate.

Answer (score -1):

> Nike's online sales have returned to the same level as before it revealed its controversial ad campaign with former San Francisco 49ers quarterback Colin Kaepernick.
>
> The campaign had sparked an initial jump in sales, with online sales climbing 27 percent between Sunday and Wednesday of Labor Day weekend, according to Edison Trends, a digital-commerce researcher.

- [CNBC article,](https://www.cnbc.com/2018/09/13/the-kaepernick-buzz-may-be-fading-nike-online-sales-return-to-levels-before-the-ad.html)  Published 8:35 AM ET Thu, 13 Sept 2018  Updated 11:05 AM ET Thu, 13 Sept 2018.

Comment: I am specifically interested in the immediate term sales boost that the campaign had. I'll look at long term trends by studying their 10-K. I appreciate your response, but it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: You need to indicate when you're copying words from another source by formatting it as a blockquote.